# How to determine in java when I'm near to the OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: java, runtime, out-of-memory, heap-size

I need to find out when I'm really close to the `OutOfMemoryError` so I can flush results to file and call `runtime.gc();`. My code is something like this:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
...
if ((1.0 * runtime.totalMemory() / runtime.maxMemory()) > 0.9) {
... flush results to file ...
  runtime.gc();
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Can someone give me a hand please?

### EDIT

I understood that I am playing with fire this way so I reasoned to a more solid and simple way of determining when I've had enough. I am currently working with the Jena model so I do a simple check: if the model has more than 550k statements then I flush so I don't run any risks.

Comment: If you want your program to fail miserably and mysteriously at random times which cannot be correlated with any outside factor, I warmly recommend you to build this into your project.

Comment: This is terrible! How about you fix the source of the `OutOfMemoryError` instead?

Comment: I was thinking to do a try/catch of the OutOfMemoryError and only then flush everything to file and call the garbage collector but still I do not want to fire the error. I just want to know when I am really near.

Comment: OOME is typically thrown as a result of the garbage collector finding that it cannot reclaim enough space to satisfy an allocation request. How you are planning to get more space if the JVM can't?

Comment: @Zeeshan I flush the results to file, dereference the variable and create new ones.

Comment: That is just so wrong. There is only one proper design: prevention, not reaction. If your application runs out of memory, tune it to use less memory at the same moment in time. Like flushing sooner rather than later.

Comment: Like I said, how do I know when to flush? I need to know when I'm near the OOME.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First**: if you want to determine if you're close to `OutOfMemoryError`, then what all you have to do is to compare the current memory with the max memory used by `JVM`, and that what you already did.

**Second**: You want to flush results to file, am wondering why you want to do that just if you close to `OutOfMemoryError`, you simply can use something like a `FileWriter` which has a buffer, so if the buffer got filled it will flush the results automatically.

**Third**: don't ever call the `GC` explicitly, its a bad practice, optimize your `JVM` memory arguments instead:

```
-Xmx -> this param to set the max memory that the JVM can allocate
-Xms -> the init memory that JVM will allocate on the start up
-XX:MaxPermSize= -> this for the max Permanent Generation memory
```

Also

```
-XX:MaxNewSize=  -> this need to be 40% from your Xmx value
-XX:NewSize= -> this need to be 40% from your Xmx value
```

These will speed up the GC.

And `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` to enable using `CMS` for the old space.

Comment: I cannot use FileWriter because I am using the Jena model to write to file so I must write an entire file at a time. I think if I increase the heap size to 1GB it will do.

Comment: You can flush periodically, i don't know how you generate your results but i believe you can do flush before get that memory leak.

Comment: And that's what I'm trying to avoid: if I know when I'm near to OOME then I can flush and avoid it.

Comment: @Ariel, what am trying to say that you don't have to be close with `OutOfMemoryError` at all, its not a healthy way, you can depends on something else.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
public class LowMemoryDetector {

    // Use a soft reference to some memory - will be held onto until GC is nearly out of memory.
    private final SoftReference<byte[]> buffer;
    // The queue that watches for the buffer to be discarded.
    private final ReferenceQueue<byte[]> queue = new ReferenceQueue<>();
    // Have we seen the low condition?
    private boolean seenLow = false;

    public LowMemoryDetector(int bufferSize) {
        // Make my buffer and add register the queue for it to be discarded to.
        buffer = new SoftReference(new byte[bufferSize], queue);
    }

    /**
     * Please be sure to create a new LMD after it returns true.
     * 
     * @return true if a memory low condition has been detected.
     */
    public boolean low () {
        // Preserve that fact that we've seen a low.
        seenLow |= queue.poll() != null;
        return seenLow;
    }
}

private static final int OneMeg = 0x100000;

public void test() {
    LowMemoryDetector lmd = new LowMemoryDetector(2*OneMeg);
    ArrayList<char[]> eatMemory = new ArrayList<>();
    int ate = 0;
    while ( !lmd.low() ) {
        eatMemory.add(new char[OneMeg]);
        ate += 1;
    }
    // Let it go.
    eatMemory = null;
    System.out.println("Ate "+ate);
}
```

it prints

```
Ate 1070
```

for me.

Use a buffer size of something larger than the largest allocation unit you are using. It needs to be big enough so that any allocation request would be satisfied if the buffer was freed.

Please remember that on a 64bit JVM it is potentially possible that you are running with many tb of memory. This approach would almost certainly encounter many difficulties in this case.